# Use Substring & patindex to extract parts of string to new columns MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a field in MS SQL that is concatenated like this TopLevel>MidLevel>Lowestlevel tis string varies in length. Sometimes the string is shorter with only a topLevel or a toplevel>MidLevel
What I need to do is take the string apart at the ">" and put the text in between into new columns/fields. 
I tried parsename which worked great until the length started changing.

What I have does not error out but does not produce anything either - except 3 empty columns.

```
SELECT 
[program_Name]

,substring([Program_Name],1, patindex([Program_Name], '>')) as UP
,substring([Program_Name],patindex([Program_Name], '>*>') - patindex([Program_Name], '>'), patindex([Program_Name], '>*>')) as MID
,substring([Program_Name],patindex([Program_Name], '>*>*>') - patindex([Program_Name], '>*>'), patindex([Program_Name], '>*>')) as LOW


 */
  FROM [dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView]
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and desire output so we can help you.

Comment: The problem I was having with the ParseName is that the length varies.  So sometimes I will have the files that will be: IT>CTO>Project  with IT being the top and CTO the mid and Proejct being the low and sometimes it will be just IT with IT being the top but IT gets put in the low. and any number of otehr combinations. I do not know how to make IT be the top or IT>Security be the top and middle using Parsename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `PARSENAME` (as long as data itself does not containt `.`):

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #tab(col) VALUES( 'TopLevel>MidLevel>Lowestlevel');

SELECT 
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(col, '>', '.'),3) AS UP,
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(col, '>', '.'),2) AS MID,
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(col, '>', '.'),1) AS LOW
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422667)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║    UP    ║   MID    ║     LOW     ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║ TopLevel ║ MidLevel ║ Lowestlevel ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Remarks:

- With `PARSENAME` you could get up to 4 levels
- `PARSENAME` works with `SYSNAME` which is alias for `NVARCHAR(128)`
- if you have `TOP.DATA>MID.DATA>LOW.DATA` you could first change `.` to `^`, then `>` to `.` and at the end once more `^` to `.`

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422670)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Using `PARSENAME` is a bit hacky so let's do it old fashion way:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(col NVARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO #tab(col) VALUES( 'TOP>MID>LOW'), ('A>B>C>D');

WITH tally AS
(
SELECT TOP 5000 rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
  FROM master..spt_values
), cte AS
( SELECT col, s.val, pos
  FROM #tab t
  CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUBSTRING('>' + t.col + '>', rn + 1,
           CHARINDEX('>', '>' + t.col + '>', rn + 1) - rn -1)AS VAL,
           pos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn)
    FROM tally
    WHERE rn <= LEN('>' + t.col + '>') - 1
      AND SUBSTRING('>' + t.col + '>', rn, 1) = '>') AS s(val, pos)
)
SELECT col, [1] AS UP, [2] AS MID, [3] AS LOW
FROM cte
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR pos IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) AS pvt;
```

Now you can have more levels(just add `[4],[5], ...` to `SELECT` column list) and so on.

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422706)**</kbd>

Comment: It should be noted that the first parameter to `PARSENAME` is a `sysname`. For SQL Server 2008 R2+ this is the equivalent of `NVARCHAR(128)` which may be inadequate if the columns are larger than that.

Comment: Well this [**PARSEMAME**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188006(v=sql.120).aspx) will work, but is tricky force the use of a function designed to make a different work. Isnt really a bad thing just need be treated carefully.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ok, I will post  CTE

Comment: @lad2025 Sorry I dont mean you are wrong, I just provide the link so OP can check the function.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Please check my update, for completness :)

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. I am no SQL expert but her is what I am doing. I pull tables from the production DB and as I insert them into the reporting DB I need to run the SQL to add these columns into that new table and and parse the data. I am not sure how to do that. separate agent job?